# Why Eclipse run web app on localhost port 13405?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, localhost, ports

I am developing web app in Eclipse Oxygen. I am running it on Tomcat v8.5 (configured to run on Tomcat instance outside Eclipse). When I click "Run as -> Run on Server" , Eclipse shows url: http://localhost:13405/appname/ or http://localhost:13405/appname/pagename.html

I wonder why it is not on default port: 8080.

Trying achieve app in Chrome, it is available on 13405. On port 8080, there is not the recent version.

Hope, somebody can explain, what port port 13405 is for? And why it is used in this situation?

Comment: Are ports specified (in the *Servers* view right-click the server and choose *Properties*)?

Comment: In _Properties_ -> _Monitoring_, I just see that Status is "Started", Type is "HTTP/1.1", Server Port is "8080" and Monitor Port is "13405", but I do not understand why _Run on Server_ redirects to port 13405 and new version is not available in browser on 8080.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the dialog of the [server's properties](https://eclipse.org/webtools/releases/2.0/newandnoteworthy/server/serversViewMenu.png)?

Comment: Here they are: [link](http://imgur.com/a/kltZi) [link](http://imgur.com/a/BVnIT)

Comment: Thx for the screenshots. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure, but I suppose that at the first time a **random port** is chosen **to be able to run more than one server in parallel** (if 13405 were not a random port, I would expect more hits by querying the web). Probably, it is similar to the web-based Eclipse help system, where a free random port is selected each time on start-up (as long as no port is specific for Eclipse help in *eclipse.ini*).

Comment: I am not able to said that what you have said is correct or not, but it seems to be true. Thanks. I still do not see what is a difference between "Server Port" and "Monitor Port"

Comment: As I understand, in this context _Server Port_ and _Monitor Port_ are synonymous. _Server Port_ is a general term, whereas _Monitor Port_ is a more specific term.

Comment: You can check my guess by creating another web app and look which port have been set.